# Input error Python 3.3

Tags: python

Whenever I use the following code, it gives me a syntax error.

```
    print('1. Can elephants jump?')
answer1 = input()
if answer1 = 'yes':
    print('Wrong! Elephants cannot jump')
if answer1 = 'no':
    print('Correct! Elephants cannot jump!'
```

I believe it has something to do with a string cannot be equal something?

Comment: It is always a good idea to post the error messages in your post too

Comment: You've got an `IndentationError` in the very first line, which prevents you from even getting to the first `SyntaxError`.

Answer (score 3):

You are using assignment (one `=`) instead of equality testing (double `==`):

```
if answer1 = 'yes':
```

and

```
if answer1 = 'no':
```

Double the `=` to `==`:

```
if answer1 == 'yes':
```

and

```
if answer1 == 'no':
```

You are also missing a closing parenthesis:

```
print('Correct! Elephants cannot jump!'
```

Add the missing `)` at the end.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a closing parenthesis at the last `print`:

```
print('Correct! Elephants cannot jump!')
#                                here--^
```

Also, you need to use `==` for comparison tests, not `=` (which is for variable assignment).

Finally, you should use `elif` to test for one thing or another.

Corrected code:

```
print('1. Can elephants jump?')
answer1 = input()
if answer1 == 'yes':
    print('Wrong! Elephants cannot jump')
elif answer1 == 'no':
    print('Correct! Elephants cannot jump!')
```

Comment: Thanks, I asked for one correction, and got 3, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Use == for comparison. Not = , that is for assignment.

You may also want to check your ()